# DotNetOpenAuth and refresh a token with MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I am tring to implemented an `OAuth2Authorization Server` and I am tring to connect to it by `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client` in a MVC 4 webclient project.

In my SPA webclient I am able to obtain an `AccessToken` overriding `QueryAccessToken` of `OAuth2Client`.

With my `AccessToken` I am able to call a REST API service and obtain successful result as user extra data.

```
....
HttpWebRequest apiRequest = 
   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(".....://localhost:4314/api/TodoList");
DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.AuthorizeRequest(apiRequest, AccessToken);
....
```

But, after some time my `AccessToken` goes to expire and I receive an error, so I need to refresh my `AccessToken` for next REST service calls.

How can I refresh my `AccessToken` inside a method of `OAuth2Client`?
Is it possible to use `ClientBase.RefreshAuthorization(....)`?

Thanks
Carmelo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet` namespace for authorization (using the access token repeatedly for web requests) is swimming upstream. That namespace has clients that are only intended for login (authentication).

A better fit for what you're doing would be to use the `WebServerClient` class, which is part of the core DotNetOpenAuth library. It automatically refreshes the access token as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in this way I can not use the same accesstoken for both authentication and call restful services.
I'm trying to use:
...
var entity = CreateQueryString(new Dictionary<string,string>{
{"Client_id", _appId},{"Client_secret", _appSecret},{"Refresh_token", Authorization.RefreshToken},{"Grant_type","refresh_token"},});
...
to obtain a new accesstoken after a restful call fails.

Do you think could work?

thanks
Carmelo

Comment: Ah, so you *are* also authenticating the user. I understand how you'd want it all done in one step. Your query string has incorrect capitalization. If you have all this data to populate it with, I suggest you call [ClientBase.RefreshAuthorization](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/v4.2/src/DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client/OAuth2/ClientBase.cs#L187) with this data filled in your own instance of `IAuthorizationState` and let DotNetOpenAuth handle the mechanics of the token refresh.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try it. Carmelo